# WordPress plugin pagination not working correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I've created a function that uses the built-in function `paginate_links`.

But the pagination isn't working correctly because the URL is being written wrong.

The URL I want looks like this `domain.com/properties/page/2/?foo=bar`

The URL that is being output is `domain.com/properties/?foo=bar/page/2/`

Here's my code

```
function paginate($max_num_pages) {
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_query->query_vars['page'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['page'] : $current = 1;
    $pagination = array(
        'base' => @add_query_arg('page','%#%'),
        'format'       => '',
        'total'        => $max_num_pages,
        'current'      => $current,
        'show_all'     => true,
        'end_size'     => 1,
        'mid_size'     => 2,
        'prev_next'    => True,
        'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
        'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
        'type'         => 'plain',
        'add_args'     => false,
        'add_fragment' => ''
    );

    if( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) 
        $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'page' );

    if( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) ) 
        $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );

    echo paginate_links( $pagination );
}
```

Comment: When you place PHP code on Stackoverflow, do not make use of the `@` error control operator. Make all errors and warnings visible instead. Also your problem just looks like a URL handling problem, why not consider to use a lightweight URL class like [`Net_URL2`](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2/) or some WP API functions to handle the URL and add the string to the [*Path* part of the URL](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) as you're interested for that?

Comment: Also a question is missing here. You write what you do, you write what you want to achieve, you write what happens instead. That's fine so far, however, you don't *explain* why you write that code that way in specific and then you miss to formulate a question as well why you wonder that it fails. E.g. explain in your own words *why* you expect the *right* output. Which parameters to `paginate_links` and which of your lines of code *should* establish that? It's not clear from your code and the documentation of the functions used (codex) why you actually expect that. Add more context to profit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me.

I had to change the `$wp_query->query_vars` to `paged` and I removed the line that checked if I was using perma links `if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );`

```
function paginate($max_num_pages) {
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;
    $pagination = array(
        'base'  => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
        'format'       => '',
        'total'        => $max_num_pages,
        'current'      => $current,
        'show_all'     => true,
        'end_size'     => 1,
        'mid_size'     => 2,
        'prev_next'    => True,
        'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
        'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
        'type'         => 'plain',
        'add_args'     => false,
        'add_fragment' => ''
    );

    //if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );
    if ( !empty($wp_query->query_vars['s']) ) $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );  
    echo paginate_links( $pagination );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation for `paginate_links`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) the default `format` looks similar to what you're after, but you're overriding that value by setting `'format' => ''`.

Try removing that option or set it to what you're after: `'format' => '?foo=bar%#%'`

Comment: I'm not a Wordpress developer, but I feel like the solution is definitely related to both the `base` and `format` options of `paginate_links`. Best of luck.

Comment: I agree. I'm diving deeper into this. Thank you for your response.

Comment: This didn't turn out to be the correct answer but I appreciate your time and effort so I'm giving you the bounty.